# How do I change my password with Zvents?

Tags: bing

I've noticed that [Bing Events](http://www.bing.com/events/) uses [Zvents](http://zvents.com). The [submit an event](http://bing.zvents.com/listings) option takes you right to Zvents. I'd like to know how to change my password on Zvents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it there is an [FAQ](http://www.zvents.com/support/help) at [Zvents proper](http://zvents.com) (not http://bing.zvents.com).

> How do I change my password? 
>   After you log in, click on the 'MyZvents' link displayed in the top right corner of any page. You can change your password by clicking on the 'Update Your Profile' link.

Or, just go here:
http://www.zvents.com/user/edit